# If $G$ is a group with $H$ a normal subgroup of it and ${\rm card}(H)=2$. Show that there exist normal subgroups of order $6,10$ and $30$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

I have that $G$ is a group with cardinality $60$. Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of it with ${\rm card}(H) = 2$.

Now, I have to show that there exist normal subgroups of order $6, 10$ and $30$.

Can you maybe give me just a hint in which direction the proof should go?

I could only get so far to show that $G/H$ is a normal subgroup with cardinality $30$.

Comment: Such problems can be solved in various different ways, some of which may be opaque to you. To get useful answers you’ll want to clarify where the question is taken from and what results have been taught to you right around that exercise. Also not that G/H isn’t a normal subgroup of G; it isn’t a subgroup at all.

Comment: This is a really helpful way to express what other people communicate with a silent close vote. Thanks for doing better than them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proof.

$G/H$ is a group of order $30$. By the Sylow theorem $G/H$ has a normal subgroup $N_1/H$ of order $5$. Hence $N_1$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ of order $10$.

**Edit:** Proof that a group $T$ of order $30$ has unique Sylow $5$-subgroup. The number of these subgroups is $1$ or $6$.

Suppose that the number of Sylow $5$-subgroups is $6$. Then there are $24$ elements of order $5$ in $T$. The number of Sylow $3$-subgroups in $T$ is $1$ or $10$. If it is $10$, then $24+10*2>30$, a contradiction. Hence there is unique Sylow 3-subgroup $S$. The factor-group $T/S$ is of order $10$, has unique order $5$ subgroup $U/S$.  Its preimage $U$ has $15$ elements and must contain all $20$ elements of order $5$, a contradiction.

The group $G/N_1$ has order $6$, so it is either a cyclic group or $S_3$, in each case it has a normal subgroup $N_2/N_1$ of order $3$. Then $N_2$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ of order $30$.

It has a normal subgroup $H$ of order $2$. Then $N_2/H$ has order $15$ and cyclic. It has unique normal subgroup $N_3/H$ of order $3$. Then $N_3$ has order $6$. If $N_3$ was not normal in $G$ then for some $g\in G$, $g^{-1}N_3g\ne N_3$. Since $H$ is normal in $G$, then
$N_3/H$ would not be normal in $N_2/H$, a contradiction. So $N_3$ is a normal in $G$ subgroup of order $6$.

Another proof that $N_3$ is normal in $G$: $N_3/H$ is unique Sylow $3$-subgroup in $N_2/H$. So it is characteristic in $N_2/H$. Hence $N_3/H$ is normal in $G/H$, hence $N_3$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: Why is $G/N_2$ necessarily cyclic?

Comment: @fitzcarraldo: It is not. It may also be $D_5$. Fixed.

Comment: @markvs Why does $U$ have 15 elements and must contain all 20 elements of order 5?

Comment: $5*3=15.$ The image of an order $5$ element has order $5$ or 1.

Comment: @markvs I'm sorry, but I don't get it yet. What I know so far is that: $(G/H) / S$ has a unique $5$-Sylow subgroup i.e. it contains exactly 5 elements of order $5$. The preimage of this unique $5$-Sylowsubgroup in $G/H$ must have $15$ elements. Why do you multiply $5$ with $3$?

Comment: It is $|U|=|S|*|U/S|=3*5$.

Comment: @markvs Oh god, I don't know how I couldn't see that. I'm just wondering why you wrote all 20 elements of order 5, although we have 24 elements of order 5? And another reason why all elements of order 5 must be in $U$ is that $U$ must be a normal subgroup as well, right? Since $U/S$ is normal.